# Display the part of the text in overflow on another div

Tags: javascript, html, overflow

HTML

```
<div id="element1"><p id="hello">test test test test ... test test test test</p></div>
<div id="element2"><p></p></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var element = document.querySelector('#element1');
if( (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight) || (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth)){
   // my element have overflow
  element.style.background = "yellow";
}
else{
  //my element don't have overflow
}
```

I use that simple javascript to detect if there is a text overflow in my paragraph (the height is fixed). But more specifically what I'm trying to do is if scrollheight bigger than offsetheight then display the part of the text in overflow on another `<div>`. (In this example element2). shouldn't be tough in javascript, should that? I haven't seen anything like this on the web and impossible to understand the problem...

Comment: If you get the string in javascript, you could fill the first div word by word (e.g. after splitting the original string by spaces) and check your condition after each word added. Once the condition is fulfilled you add the next words to you other div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is heavily based on Fuzzzzel's clever idea of iterating over every word and adding them to the first element until it overflows. Generally, such a process is very slow and would impact the UX, *(what if the text were 10000 words)*, but it's the only possible way I can think of.

**What my answer does differently:**

1. My answer respects the `padding` of the element and will not insert another word if the element is full, while Fuzzzzel's doesn't, as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f8x1ne0h/1/).
2. I use `textContent` which is a faster way of getting and setting text in `HTML` nodes, because it doesn't attempt to parse `HTML`.
3. This answer is steadily `~100x` faster than Fuzzzzel's.

**Code:**

```
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
;(function () {
  var
    /* Cache the elements. */
    element1 = document.getElementById("element1"),
    element2 = document.getElementById("element2"),

    /* Cache the paragraphs. */
    p1 = document.querySelector("#element1 > p"),
    p2 = document.querySelector("#element2 > p"),

    /* Cache the content of element1 > p and split it at the spaces. */
    content = p1.textContent.split(/\s/),

    /* Create an array with the final content of the first paragraph. */
    p1final = [],

    /* Create a flag the signals whether the content has overflowed in element1. */
    overflowed = false;

  /* Empty the first paragraph. */
  p1.textContent = "";

  /* Iterate over every word of the content. */
  [].forEach.call(content, function (word, index) {
    /* Check whether the content has already overflowed. */
    if (overflowed) {
      /* Add the word to the second paragraph. */
      p2.textContent += (index ? " " : "") + word;
    }
    else {
      /* Define the variables. */
      var hasXOverflow, hasYOverflow;

      /* Add the word to the first paragraph. */
      p1.textContent += (index ? " " : "") + word;

      /* Cache the overflow data. */
      hasXOverflow = element1.offsetWidth < element1.scrollWidth;
      hasYOverflow = element1.offsetHeight < element1.scrollHeight;

      /* Check whether the content overflows. */
      if (hasXOverflow || hasYOverflow) {
        /* Remove the word that made the first paragraph overflow
        by using the all previous words (saved in p1final). */
        p1.textContent = p1final.join(" ");

        /* Add the word to the second paragraph. */
        p2.textContent += (index ? " " : "") + word;

        /* Set the oveflowed flag to true. */
        overflowed = true;
      }
      else {
        /* Add the word to the p1final array. */
        p1final[index] = word;
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

Check out [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8x1ne0h/) or the following snippet for a demonstration of the code.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
;(function () {
  var
    /* Cache the elements. */
    element1 = document.getElementById("element1"),
    element2 = document.getElementById("element2"),
    
    /* Cache the paragraphs. */
    p1 = document.querySelector("#element1 > p"),
    p2 = document.querySelector("#element2 > p"),
    
    /* Cache the content of element1 > p and split it at the spaces. */
    content = p1.textContent.split(/\s/),
    
    /* Create an array with the final content of the first paragraph. */
    final = [],
    
    /* Create a flag the signals whether the content has overflowed in element1. */
    overflowed = false;
    
  /* Empty the first paragraph. */
  p1.textContent = "";
  
  /* Iterate over every word of the content. */
  [].forEach.call(content, function (word, index) {
    /* Check whether the content has already overflowed. */
    if (overflowed) {
      /* Add the word to the second paragraph. */
      p2.textContent += (index ? " " : "") + word;
    }
    else {
      /* Define the variables. */
      var hasXOverflow, hasYOverflow;
        
      /* Add the word to the first paragraph. */
      p1.textContent += (index ? " " : "") + word;
      
      /* Cache the overflow data. */
      hasXOverflow = element1.offsetWidth < element1.scrollWidth;
      hasYOverflow = element1.offsetHeight < element1.scrollHeight;
      
      /* Check whether the content overflows. */
      if (hasXOverflow || hasYOverflow) {
        /* Remove the word that made the first paragraph overflow
        by using the all previous words (saved in final). */
        p1.textContent = final.join(" ");
        
        /* Add the word to the second paragraph. */
       p2.textContent += (index ? " " : "") + word;
        
        /* Set the oveflowed flag to true. */
        overflowed = true;
      }
      else {
        /* Add the word to the final array. */
        final[index] = word;
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
[id ^= "element"] {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

#element1 {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {margin: 0}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<div id="element1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
</div>
<div id="element2">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

**Speedtest Results:**

<sup>*(2,857 words 19,040 characters)*</sup>

1. This answer *([jsFiddle used](https://jsfiddle.net/f8x1ne0h/3/))*:

   - `81.217041015625 ms`
   - `87.778076171875 ms`
   - `89.469726562500 ms`
   - `77.690673828125 ms`
   - `62.181152343750 ms`
2. Fuzzzzel's answer *([jsFiddle used](https://jsfiddle.net/f8x1ne0h/2/))*:

   - `8468.773193359375 ms`
   - `8544.271972656250 ms`
   - `9054.047851562500 ms`
   - `8470.183837890625 ms`
   - `8730.039306640625 ms`

Comment: True, the textContent property is faster and as you stated the first word that makes the container overflow should already be added to the next container. I did not take this into account. So your answer is the better/improved one. Most likely the quickest way would be to use CSS columns to divide a text between multiple containers but that was not asked ;-)

Comment: However, this is not about optimizing for speed, but two more suggestions: 1. After the first word does not fit, internally concatenate the remaining string and add it to the second container. This solution skips any DOM manipulations but one for the second container. 2. Or do this recoursively. The function tries to add the given text. If it does not fit split it in half and put the first part to the same function:. If it does fit, do the same with the second half. Keep the parts that fit in memory for either container or return them from the function. This always takes max sqrt(n) attempts.

Comment: Sorry, must not be sqrt(n) but log2(n).

Comment: whoa guys, I'm impressed! this is AMAZING. I digged a lot on google to find something similar.. Thanks a lot, I've learn something !

Comment: Guys, do you know why the last line of the first div has always only one word. i.e "consequat" should be on the same line than "commodo" see here [link1](https://ibb.co/jiy8MH) . That always does that in all configurations.... other i.e [link2](https://ibb.co/eAbpTx)

Comment: You are right @Fuzzzzel; there are still tweaks that can be made to improve the code, but this is probably outside the scope of the question 

Comment: I'm glad you found a working solution to your problem @Odjone. Couldn't have done it without Fuzzzzel! Be sure to check out the code in the answer again. I've added a line of code under `p1.textContent = p1final.join(" ")`, because when the overflow occurred, the word that caused it was dumped completely instead of being pushed to the second element.

Comment: As regards the images you've linked, I can't replicate the issue you are facing @Odjone. I tried adjusting the `height`, `width` and `padding` of the `div` elements, but the code works perfectly. Can you create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) with the exact code you are using so I can see what's causing it?

Comment: @AngelPolitis . Sure. Here is a JSfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kret83vh/) and here is what is displayed on my screen [link](https://ibb.co/bFsD6H) .. "ut aliquip" should be after "nisi" which is the last word of the first div. I am on Chrome

Comment: @Odjone in your jsfiddle you are using Fuzzzzel's code which, as I mentioned in my answer, has a problem with the last word of the first element. _`nisi`_ should be on the second box, which is evident by looking at the space from the top of the box and the space from the bottom. Clearly, the space from the bottom is smaller. If you use [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/kret83vh/1/) it will work as expected. When using my code, if you pay attention there is now more space to the top. That happens, because the height you have set is not enough to contain another sentence of that `font-size`.

Comment: oh yes.. I was playing with two files... I'm very tired. Definitely need to sleep =) . Anyway code works perfectely, was my bad

Answer (score 1):

To put my comment into some code:

- Take the text you want to split and store it into a variable
- split the text into pieces (words)
- Add word for word to the first div, until it is full
- Then add the following words to the other div

Here's the piece of code I came up with using your piece of html:

```
    function addWord(word) {
        // Query the divs to measure and the containing paragraph
        const element1 = document.querySelector('#element1');
        const p1 = element1.querySelector('p');
        const element2 = document.querySelector('#element2');
        const p2 = element2.querySelector('p');

        // Test if the div is full
        if ((element1.offsetHeight < element1.scrollHeight) || (element1.offsetWidth < element1.scrollWidth)) {

            // If full, add the text to second div
            p2.innerHTML += ' ' + word;
        } else {

            // If not full add the text to first div
            p1.innerHTML += ' ' + word;
        }
    }

    // Execute this part after your DOM is loaded

    // Query text you want to put into the two divs
    let text = document.querySelector('#element1 p').innerHTML;

    // Split the text into words (roughly)
    let words = text.split(' ');

    // Empty the text you just loaded
    document.querySelector('#element1 p').innerHTML = '';

    // Add the text to the divs word by word
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        addWord(words[i]);
    }
```

Comment: very interesting... I'll try to implement that today inside my php =)

Comment: the idea sounds very good theoretically but I cant make it works..I get some "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" errors.

Comment: There's no p-tag in your element2 so it might not be working, since addWord adds to the first p-tag in element2.

Comment: Yes I thought that could be that but I had exactly the same result [link](https://ibb.co/mFOPdx)

Comment: @Fuzzzzel I crafted your idea into an answer of my own providing a slightly different approach. I made sure to provide credit and upvote yours for your great work 

Comment: @Fuzzzzel you're a genius. I ticked Angel's answer in order to help people in my case. I think his method is much faster for large content. But it is so unfair. You did the clever part. respect buddy ! That was a big issue for me. If you have a paypal or similar, I would be more than happy to buy you a beer ! Cheers from LDN